# Codeigniter and Tank Auth - new registration field being incorrectly added to database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, tankauth

I've created a new field in the registration form:

```
//goes on top of page along with other form vars
$phone = array(
    'name'  => 'phone',
    'id'    => 'phone',
    'value' => set_value('phone'),
    'maxlength' => $this->config->item('phone_max_length', 'tank_auth'),
    'size'  => 30,
);

//inserted into form
<?php echo form_label('Phone number', $phone['id']); ?>
<?php echo form_input($phone); ?>
<?php echo form_error($phone['name']); ?>
```

And I've [updated the register controller in the necessary places,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkfHa.jpg)

as well [as updating the Tank Auth library](http://imgur.com/QyErDX7) in `rootdir/application/libraries/Tank_auth.php`

I've also created a phone column in the users table. 
However, say the mobile phone input was 07879526831, in the table it ends up as 2147483647! Really weird, and I have no clue why. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: What's the data-type of your phone- column in your db???

Comment: @elavarasanlee integer

Comment: he he he! :D Integer can't take value as big as 10 digits... Change it to  `Bigint` or use `Varchar (13)`!

Comment: Oh god! It's so simple and I spent so long on this! Thank you so much - one more question - it seems to be cutting one digit off the beginning, why may that be?

Comment: I did that mistake that's I know... :P That's because its again `Bigint` Will ignore preceding 0..

Comment: Excellent! Var char it is, thank you and take care.

Comment: Yup, If U want to store numbers preceding with 0 or country codes (e.g., +91) Varchar can take best care of it whereas Integer and Bigint will fail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2147483647 is the largest value that can be stored in a signed 32-bit integer. For a phone number, assuming you have a fixed set of characters, try using a char(10) for example. Or you could use a varchar, if your phone numbers will be stored with varying lengths.